# How to add Images in a tensorflow.js model and train the model for given images labels

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-recognition, tensor, tensorflow.js

We are using TensorFlow.js to create and train the model. We use tf.fromPixels() function to convert an image into tensor.
We want to create a custom model with the below properties:

AddImage( HTML_Image_Element, 'Label'): Add an imageElement with a custom label
Train() / fit() : Train this custom model with associated labels
Predict(): Predict the images with their associated label, and it will return the predicted response with the attached label of every image.
For better understanding let's take an example:
Let's say we have three images for prediction i.e: img1, img2, img3 with three labels 'A', 'B' and 'C' respectively.
So we want to create and train our model with these images and respective labels like below :
When user want to predict 'img1' then it shows the prediction 'A', similarly, for 'img2' predict with 'B' and for 'img3' predict with 'C'

Please suggest to me how can we create and train this model.

```html
This is webpage we used to create a model with images and its associate labels:
 
<apex:page id="PageId" showheader="false">
    <head>
        <title>Image Classifier with TensorFlowJS</title> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.2"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div id="output_field"></div>
    <img id="imgshow" src="{!$Resource.cat}" crossorigin="anonymous" width="400" height="300" />
    
    <script>
    async function learnlinear(){
        
        
        //img data set
        const imageHTML = document.getElementById('imgshow');           
        console.log('imageHTML::'+imageHTML.src);
        
        //convert to tensor 
        const tensorImg = tf.fromPixels(imageHTML);
        tensorImg.data().then(async function (stuffTensImg){
            console.log('stuffTensImg::'+stuffTensImg.toString());
            
        });
        const model = tf.sequential();
            
        model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
            kernelSize: 5,
            filters: 20,
            strides: 1,
            activation: 'relu',
            inputShape: [imageHTML.height, imageHTML.width, 3],
        }));
        
        model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
            poolSize: [2, 2],
            strides: [2, 2],
        }));
        
        model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
        
        model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2));
        
        // Two output values x and y
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({
            units: 2,
            activation: 'tanh',
        }));
        
        // Use ADAM optimizer with learning rate of 0.0005 and MSE loss
        model.compile({
            optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.0005),
            loss: 'meanSquaredError',
        });
        await model.fit(tensorImg, {epochs: 500});
        model.predict(tensorImg).print();
    }
    learnlinear();
    </script>
   
</apex:page>
```

we got the following error while running the code snippet:
tfjs@0.11.2:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s). but got an array with shape 300,400,3
    at new t (tfjs@0.11.2:1)
    at standardizeInputData (tfjs@0.11.2:1)
    at t.standardizeUserData (tfjs@0.11.2:1)
    at t. (tfjs@0.11.2:1)
    at n (tfjs@0.11.2:1)
    at Object.next (tfjs@0.11.2:1)
    at tfjs@0.11.2:1
    at new Promise ()
    at __awaiter$15 (tfjs@0.11.2:1)
    at t.fit (tfjs@0.11.2:1)

[This error coming while passing this sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzP4w.png)

Comment: Your error message is pretty straight forward. The tensor expected was `4` but it received an input of `300,400,3`. Just reshape the data to be 4-dimensional like `np.expand_dims(some-np-array, axis = 3)`

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to reshape your tensor data.

The data you passed in to your model should be one dimension bigger than the inputShape. Actually `predict` takes an array of elements of shape `InputShape`. The number of elements is the batch size. Therefore your image data should have the following shape `[batchsize, ...inputShape]` (using the ellipsis for rest parameter to indicate that the later part of the shape is equal to that of `inputShape`)

Since you're training with only one element (which does not really happen in real case) one simply needs to use a batchsize of 1.

```
model.predict(tensorImg.expandDims(0)).print()
```

Comment: Now I did a successful training with an image object. Since my task is based on Image Labeling/Image Recognition so we want to associate a "Label" with each image. So when we are trying to train a model with an image as well as a Label, then the model doesn't store the label in his 'model.json' file. So can you please guide us to train an image with a Label also.

Comment: @Adarsh4sfdc it is unclear what you're asking. When training there are always labels. So I can't understand what difference you are referring to by "training with a label" and "training without a label". Consider asking your new question separately in a new post with more details. If this answer above helped you don't forget to upvote it and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @edkeveked can you please help me there ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642621/create-a-training-data-set-with-image-captured-from-html5-canvas-and-custom-labe

Comment: @Greyfrog I will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** You simply have to resize your data using `np.expand_dims()` or `np.reshape()`.

First, let's generate some random tensor that mimics your current tensor input -

```
# Some random numpy array
In [20]: x = np.random.random((2,2,4))

In [21]: x
Out[21]: 
array([[[0.8454901 , 0.75157647, 0.1511371 , 0.53809724],
        [0.50779498, 0.41321185, 0.45686143, 0.80532259]],

       [[0.93412402, 0.02820063, 0.5452628 , 0.8462806 ],
        [0.4315332 , 0.9528761 , 0.69604215, 0.538589  ]]])

# Currently your tensor is a similar 3D shape like x
In [22]: x.shape
Out[22]: (2, 2, 4)
```

---

Now you can convert it to a 4D tensor like so -

```
[23]: y = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 3)

In [24]: y
Out[24]: 
array([[[[0.8454901 ],
         [0.75157647],
         [0.1511371 ],
         [0.53809724]],

        [[0.50779498],
         [0.41321185],
         [0.45686143],
         [0.80532259]]],


       [[[0.93412402],
         [0.02820063],
         [0.5452628 ],
         [0.8462806 ]],

        [[0.4315332 ],
         [0.9528761 ],
         [0.69604215],
         [0.538589  ]]]])

In [25]: y.shape
Out[25]: (2, 2, 4, 1)
```

You can find the `np.expand_dims` documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html?highlight=expand_dims#numpy.expand_dims).

---

**EDIT:** Here's a one-liner

```
np.reshape(np.ravel(x), (x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2], 1)).shape
```

You can see the`np.reshape` documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Comment: Using  resize_image = tf.reshape(tensorImg, [-1, 300, 300, 4]), to resize but still it give same error Error: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s). but got array with shape 300,400,3

Comment: Maybe you're not using `resize_image` while passing the inputs. Also, shouldn't it be `resize_image = tf.reshape(tensorImg, [-1, 300, 400, 3])` ?

Comment: Now I did a successful training with an image object. Since my task is based on Image Labeling/Image Recognition so we want to associate a "Label" with each image. So when we are trying to train a model with an image as well as a Label, then the model doesn't store the label in his 'model.json' file. So can you please guide us to train an image with a Label also.