# tensorflow.js getting Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

simple question and im sure answer is straightforward but im really struggling to match model shape with tensor fitting into model.

this simple code

```
    let tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

    let features = {
        x: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        y: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      }

    let tensorfeature  = tf.tensor2d(Object.values(features))

    console.log(tensorfeature.shape)

    const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense(
            {
            inputShape: tensorfeature.shape,
            units: 1
        }
            ))
            const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.005);
            model.compile({optimizer: optimizer, loss: 'meanAbsoluteError'}); 
            model.fit(tensorfeature,
                {epochs: 5}
                )
```

Results in Error: Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 2,9

tried multiple things with reshape, slice, etc with no luck. Can someone point me what exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.fit` takes at least two parameters x, y which are either tensors or array of tensors. The config object is the third parameter.

Also, the feature(`tensorfeature`) tensor passed as argument to model.fit should be one dimension higher than the `inputShape` of the model. Since `tensorfeature.shape` is used as the `inputShape`, if we want to traing the model with `tensorfeature` its dimension should be expanded. It can be done using `reshape` or `expandDims`.

```
model.fit(tensorfeature.expandDims(0))
// or possibly
model.fit(tensorfeature.reshape([1, ...tensorfeature.shape])
```

This shape mismatch between the model and the training data has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790230/expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-shape-a-but-got-array-with-shape-b/51791892#51791892) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689808/how-to-add-images-in-a-tensorflow-js-model-and-train-the-model-for-given-images/54690176#54690176)