# Error: Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 1,9

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Im really new to tensorflow.js and im trying to do simple model that tell you on what side of the canvas you cliked

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(
         tf.layers.dense({
           units: 200,
           activation: "sigmoid",
           inputShape: [0, 1],
         })
       );
       model.add(
         tf.layers.dense({
           units: 2,
           activation: "softmax",
         })
       );
       model.compile({
         optimizer: optimizer,
         loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
         metrics: ["accuracy"],
       });
```

my training and testing data

```
        const yTrain = tf.tensor2d(
          [10, 130, 60, 20, 150, 110, 3, 160, 99],
          [1, 9]
        );
        const xTrain = tf.tensor2d([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 9]);

        const yTest = tf.tensor2d(
          [5, 106, 33, 88, 104, 140, 7, 60, 154],
          [1, 9]
        );
        const xTest = tf.tensor2d([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The inputShape is of size 2, therefore, the features (here xtrain and xtest) should be of dimension 3.

Additionnally, it does not make sense to have a dimension size to be 0 (that will mean that the tensor is empty).

Given your xtrain and xtest shape, `[a, b]`, the inputShape, should be `[b]`.

This shape mismatch between the model and the training data has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790230/expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-shape-a-but-got-array-with-shape-b/51791892#51791892) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689808/how-to-add-images-in-a-tensorflow-js-model-and-train-the-model-for-given-images/54690176#54690176)

Comment: I still don't understand can you tell me what the input shape should be?

Comment: inputShape should be `[9]` and the last unit should be `[9]` given the shape of `xtrain` and `ytrain`. Though, it will make the error vanish away, it won't necessary be enough to have a good accuracy. You can look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943498/model-is-not-learning/55954415#55954415