# Tensor has disposed

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow.js

Most of the TensorFlow JS examples uses pre-trained model in the browser for prediction.

Here I am trying to create my own data in the browser and train the model with it.

Finally I have reached a point where I think I am close to creating a dataset which can be feed to a model.fit() to train the model

I have two arrays, one containing images and other containing labels.

```
let images = []
let labels = []
```

I am using a method to capture images from the canvas and push it in the images array.

```
function getImage() {
        return tf.tidy(() => {
            const image = tf.browser.fromPixels($('#mycanvas')[0]);
            const batchedImage = image.expandDims(0);
            const norm = batchedImage.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255)).sub(tf.scalar(1));
            return norm;
        });
    }
```

So I push an image and a label to the arrays whenever I press any of the arrow key

```
let collectData = (label) =>{
    tf.tidy(() => {
        const img = getImage();
        img.print() // check if it is a tensor
        //imges.concat(img)
        images.push(img)
        labels.push(label) // labels are 0,1,2
     })
 }
```

After creating the arrays with training dataset, I pass these into model.fit() method to start the training.

```
let fitModel = async () => { 
        let imageSet = tf.stack(images);
        let labelSet = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(lables, 'int32'), 3); 

        if (currentModel == null) {
            currentModel = createModel();
            currentModel.summary();
        }

        await currentModel.fit(imageSet, labelSet, {
            batchSize: 4,
            epochs: 20,
            shuffle: true,
            validationSplit: 0.1,
            callbacks: {
                onTrainBegin: () => console.log("Training Start"),
                onTrainEnd: () => console.log("Traing End"),
                onBatchEnd: async (num, log) => {
                    await tf.nextFrame();
                    console.log(log)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Here **tf.stack(images);** throws error stating - **Tensor has disposed**. I don't understand why that's happening. Technically this should work as stated in the official document.

```
const a = tf.tensor1d([1, 2]);
const b = tf.tensor1d([3, 4]);
const c = tf.tensor1d([5, 6]);
let p = []
p.push(a)
p.push(b)
p.push(c)
console.log(p)
tf.stack(p).print();
```

So I tried another thing - tf.stack(tf.tensor(images)) and I get error Tensor has disposed.

Another thing I though would give a try was - tf.concat() which also didn't work. Anyone has any idea how can I create trainable dataset like this.

My first hidden layer has conv2d with inputShape(150,300,3) and output layer has unit:3.

Any help would be really appreciated. Please explain your answers for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensors are disposed because you call `tf.tidy` before using them. To use the tensor `img` and clean all intermediates tensors, it has to be explicitly returned from the callback of `tf.tidy`

```js
const img = tf.tidy(() => {
        const im = getImage();
        return im;
        // since im is returned, it will not be disposed;
        // but all unused intermediate tensors will be cleaned up
     })

images.push(img)
labels.push(label) // labels are 0,1,2
```

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for replying. This resolved my problem but I am getting this error - 

Error: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s). but got array with shape 15,1,150,300,3

Comment: When I pass the imageArray just like without stacking I get this error-  


Error: Error when checking model input: the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 Tensor(s), but instead got the following list of Tensor(s): Tensor

Comment: I fixed this error and model started training, but I have another problem. My model.fit() show the losss is either greater than 1 which 1.66666666 or 1.3333333 when activation was relu. On softmax activation the loss was 0.666666666666, constant Because of these my model shows no predcition and constant one prediction result [-1,1,1] or [1,-1,1] depend when I use relu or softmax.

Comment: Could you please open a new question with the issue you now have and mark this one as resolved ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I wanted to try few things before bothering you. I posted a new question here please take a look. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67671578/tensorflowjs-model-doesnt-predict-multiclass-data-properly