# TensorflowJS model doesn't predict multiclass data properly

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

As a beginner, I have tried build a really simple multi-class classifier in tensorflowJS which is suppose to predict the direction of my eye sight.

Step 1: I created data set in the browser to train my model where I am storing images of my eyes rendered by webcam on a HTML5 canvas. I use arrow keys to label my images as 0=left,1=normal and 2=right. To train the model, I convert these lables using tf.onHot() before passing to the method.

```
// data collection 
let imageArray = [];
let labelArray = [];

let collectData = (label) => {
    const img = tf.tidy(() => {
        const captureImg = getImage();
        //console.log(captureImg.shape)
        return captureImg;
    })
    imageArray.push(img)
    labelArray.push(label) //--- labels are 0,1,2
}

// label conversion  
let labelSet = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(labelArray, 'int32'), 3);
```

Step 2: Instead of loading any per-trained model, I used my custom model that I built using tensorflowJS.

```
let createModel = () => {
        const model = tf.sequential();
        let config_one = {
            kernelSize: 3,
            filters: 40,
            strides: 1,
            activation: 'relu',
            inputShape: [imageHeight, imageWidth, imageChannels]
        }
        model.add(tf.layers.conv2d(config_one));

        let config_two = {
            poolSize: [2, 2],
            strides: [2, 2],
        }
        model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d(config_two));

        model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
        model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2));

        // Two output values x and y
        let congfig_output = {
            units: 3,
            activation: 'tanh',
        }
        model.add(tf.layers.dense(congfig_output));

        // Use ADAM optimizer with learning rate of 0.0005 and MSE loss
        let config_compile = {
            optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.00005),
            loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
        }
        model.compile(config_compile);

        tf.memory()

        return model;
    }
```

**Problems** : There are several problems I am facing right now.

1. When I use meanSquared as loss function and adam learning rate 0.000005, my model starts predicting but it only predicts two of the eye's state normal and left/right so to do multi-class classification, I changed loss function to categoricalCrossentropy but the result is still same or sometime worst.
2. I tried other combination of hyper parameters but no luck. The worst situation I got into was my loss function was showing only three constant values repeatedly.
3. My browser would crashed in some case where - if - I pass too much data or use other type of optimizer in compile config such as sgd or anything else. When I did a quick search on google, I found I can use tf.memory() to check any memory leak which could be causing browser crash but that line didn't log anything in the console.
4. I was adjusting various values and parameters in the code and training the model which made it work sometimes, partially, and most of the time didn't even work. It was all hit and trial. Eventually I learned about parameters to use for loss function in the compile method and activation function in con2d input layer but other stuff is still confusing such as - number of epochs, batch size, learning rate in adam etc.
5. I understood or I think I understood these - kernalsize, filters, strides, inputshape but still have no idea how to decide number of layers various hyper parameters etc.

**Edit** -  this is what I get after updating the code as per the suggestion. I still don't proper classification. I am training with minimum of 1000+ images.

A. I still get the loss recurring with fixed valeus

B. Accuracy is also repeating itself with 1, 0.5 and 0

```
function getImage() {
        return tf.tidy(function () {
            const image = tf.browser.fromPixels($('#eyes')[0]);
            const batchedImage = image.expandDims(0);
            const norm = batchedImage.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255)).sub(tf.scalar(1));
            return norm;
        });
    }
```

Here are the console output

[image]
[image]

**Sample images -**

[image: LEFT]
[image: RIGHT]
[image: NORMAL]

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious thing to me that is wrong with this is your output layer's activation function, where you use `tanh` you should be using `softmax` instead. Next, your learning rate is way to low try setting it to `0.001` which is a good default to use.

You also probably don't need dropout as you have not gotten any results to justify that the model is overfitting. You could also add in more convolutional layers to this, try the example below.

```
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    inputShape: [28, 28, 1],
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 8,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
}));

model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: [2, 2],
    strides: [2, 2],
}));

model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 16,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
}));

model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: [2, 2],
    strides: [2, 2],
}));

model.add(tf.layers.flatten());

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: 3,
    activation: 'softmax',
}));

const LEARNING_RATE = 0.001;
const optimizer = tf.train.adam(LEARNING_RATE);

model.compile({
    optimizer: optimizer,
    loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
    metrics: ['accuracy'],
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. I have updated my question with console output. Please check.

Comment: Ok have you normalized your images from values `0-255` to `0-1` before passing it to the model?

Comment: yes, I have.  Check the question with the update getImage code()

Comment: Could you include a sample of an image from each class?

Comment: done. I have added sample images for the three labels.