# Why the output of model.predict() is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a really basic model built with tensorflowjs. It should work as it is directly copied from the google tensorflow tutorial. I just converted that code into a class for the re-usability. Everytime I pass some data to predict, it returns undefined.

```
class TFModel {

     constructor() {
         this.xs = tf.randomUniform([10000, 2]);
         this.ys = tf.randomUniform([10000, 1]);
         this.valXs = tf.randomUniform([1000, 2]);
         this.valYs = tf.randomUniform([1000, 1]);
         this.model = tf.sequential();
     }

     init() {
         this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({
             units: 1,
             inputShape: [2]
         }));
         this.model.compile({
             loss: 'meanSquaredError',
             optimizer: 'sgd',
             metrics: ['MAE']
         });
     }

     async train() {
         await this.model.fit(this.xs, this.ys, {
             epochs: 4,
             validationData: [this.valXs, this.valYs]
         });
     }

     predict(data, callback) {
         let transData = tf.tensor(data)
         console.log(transData)
         this.model.predict(transData, result => {
             console.log("Result Predict", result)
             // callback(result)
         })
     }

     dispose() {

     }

 }
```

Here is how I am calling the above class

```
model = new TFModel();
model.init()
model.train().then(data => {
    console.log("Resul Predict", data)
})

model.predict([
    [3, 3]
], result => {
    //  console.log("Result Predict", result)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code:

1. The return type of `model.fit()` is a Promise, but when the Promise is successfully resolved, there is no data returned. So this code:

   ```js
   model.train().then(data => {
       console.log("Resul Predict", data)
   })
   ```

   would not make sense. Your `then()` function is called, but the `data` will be `undefined` since `fit()` does not return any data. It trains the model and any updates are present in the model itself.
2. There is no callback function to be passed as argument to [model.predict()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Sequential.predict) - as in, the function does not take a callback function as an argument. So this code:

   ```js
   this.model.predict(transData, result => {
       console.log("Result Predict", result)
       // callback(result)
   })
   ```

   would not make sense either. The full method should be:

   ```
   predict(data, callback) {
       let transData = tf.tensor(data)
       console.log(transData)
       callback(this.model.predict(transData))
   }
   ```

   You are passing the the result of `model.predict()` to the callback. When you do that, you will then get the Tensor output predicted.

If I uncomment the statement in your callback function:

```js
model.predict([
    [3, 3]
], result => {
    console.log("Result Predict", result) // Uncommented this line
})
```

I then get the output as:

```sh
Result Predict Tensor {
  kept: false,
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 1, 1 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  size: 1,
  strides: [ 1 ],
  dataId: {},
  id: 21,
  rankType: '2',
  scopeId: 5
}
```

You can use `Tensor.print()` to get the predicted value and proceed further.

Comment: First of all I made a really stupid mistake. I am glad that you pointed out. I totally forgot about my async await function. I don't know how did I miss that. That was really dumb of me.  That actually fixed everything. Now everything is working fine as expected. I should go to bed.  

Sorry., if I can ask you to extend your help here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815952/vue3-app-with-tensorflowjs-throws-typeerror-cannot-read-property-backend-of-u/67936096#67936096

Answer (score 0):

I think that the train() doesn't fulfilled.

```js
model.train().then(() => {
  model.predict([3, 3])
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it has already been solved. But you could help me resolve the problem in my another post -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815952/vue3-app-with-tensorflowjs-throws-typeerror-cannot-read-property-backend-of-u/67936096#67936096